# Getting date indices of unique column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame that looks like such:

```
                                contractID
Date                                      
1982-09-16  (SPZ1982, 1982-12-16 00:00:00)
1982-09-17  (SPZ1982, 1982-12-16 00:00:00)
1982-09-20  (SPZ1982, 1982-12-16 00:00:00)
                                   ...
2018-09-27  (SPZ2018, 2018-12-21 00:00:00)
2018-09-28  (SPZ2018, 2018-12-21 00:00:00)
2018-10-01  (SPZ2018, 2018-12-21 00:00:00)
```

I have repeating `contractID`s and I want to efficiently perform an operation on these ID's, like such:

```
def query(df, tup, startDate, endDate):
    ID = tup[0]
    ExpirationDate = tup[1]
    panel = df.loc[ID].loc[ExpirationDate].loc[startDate:endDate]
    return panel

df = pd.DataFrame()
print('acquiring daily data...')
for tup in contractUse['contractID'].unique():
    panel = query(rawData, tup, startDate, endDate)
    if df.empty:
        df = panel
    else:
        df = df.append(panel, verify_integrity=False)

return df
```

Where `contractUse` is the DataFrame introduced above. I only want to iterate over the unique values. As I iterate over the unique values, I need to get the index value of when that unique value started, and the index value of when that unique value stopped. I then provide this `startDate` and `endDate` of the unique value to my `query` function. Is there a quick way to do this in pandas?

Comment: the start & stop indeces are what the question is referring to, the function query is now in the post as well for clarification

Comment: My desired output is simply the results of the query function, what I'm having trouble with is acquiring its parameters, startDate and endDate. I updated the post to explain what they are.

Comment: @Évariste Galois, I believe jpp is asking that you actually copy/paste the desired output as a dataframe. As it stands right now, this question is fairly hard to follow and makes it hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things you *need* to do:

1. Don't use a series of tuples. Split this into 2 separate series.
2. Use `GroupBy` to split your dataframe into chunks depending on a column.

So first split your `contractID` series:

```
df[['key', 'contract_date']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('contractID').values.tolist())
```

Then group by the newly created `key` series:

```
g = df.groupby('key')
```

Extracting "start and end" indices for a group is now as simple as extracting a group and looking at its index. For example:

```
idx_start, idx_end = g.get_group('SPZ1982').index[[0, -1]]
```

Comment: The solution makes sense, however it seems like converting my tuple column to two columns is making the DF have 2 NaN & NaT columns... but the way it's converted looks correct to me. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The issue was how I was constructing the new DataFrame, using the `columns` and `index` params of the constructor solved my issue. This is a very elegant solution, thanks!